# How to make objects move along a path in real units (km/h; m/s; etc...) with geometry nodes?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, units

I’m building a setup to make a character walk through a path using a Bézier curve, but I'm having a problem establishing the velocity

#### The problem

In my node setup I was able to change the length of the Bézier curve and still maintain the object travel velocity constant.

However, I’m not sure how to set the nodes in a way that I can input the velocity in real world units, *such as kilometer per hour or meters per second*.

[image]

#### Node Setup

I’m not sure if the velocity in this current setup makes sense, and the object is moving in a real world unit or is just arbitrary.

[image]

Comment: Is this the setup you're seeking?: https://i.imgur.com/swJAM2b.png Input the speed you want your character to have. With default scene units, it would be in meters/seconds (because Blender uses m as unit base, and you only have seconds available as a node output). Divide curve length by that, and you have your total travel time. "0-to-TravelTime" is the whole movement, so you map that to 0-1 factor. Current time (Scene seconds) would be the current factor in relation to that. Add your time shifts and speed multipliers as desired.

Comment: @Kuboå That is what I was aiming for. Correct if I'm wrong: If I divide the velocity input by 3,6, wouldn't it make the final velocity in km/h? like that: https://i.imgur.com/iOBReMn.jpeg

Comment: Sure: https://i.imgur.com/ElfR1BP.png Is it not working for you? If not, could you share your setup (you could simplify it with a cube instead of woman etc) so it's easier to check?

Comment: It is working, thank you! I was just pondering about the km/h setup so I could repurpose this node group for vehicles as well. I wanted to mark your comment as the answer to my question but stackexchange doesn't allow me to do this to comments.

Comment: Oh good. It was a comment made in passing so I didn't wanna post it as an answer in case it was erroneous. I'll make it into an answer so you can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Blender is set to use *meters* as its base unit. Since the `Scene Time` node provides you with *Seconds*, unless you manipulate them further with `Math` nodes, your speed will happen to be *meters per second*. In your example, a barebones setup could like this:

[image]

You input your character's speed in *m/s*, and divide the length of your walking path by that, which results in your total travel time (in *seconds*). Since you want to use that travel time as the end point of your curve's *factor* (when that many seconds have passed, your character will have walked exactly the length of the curve—so the factor will be $1$), you need to `Map Range` the whole movement, using the travel time as the *Max*, and the `Scene Time` as the current value in relation to that. You can then employ various `Math` nodes to shift the time or multiply the speed.

If you'd like to switch between *m/s* and *km/h* depending on the object you're moving (human vs car), you can use a setup like this (where you would use a single value, but change its units between *m/s* and *km/h* with a switch):

[image]